# How would I go about converting NPOI.SS to NPOI.XSSF?

Tags: c#, npoi

I'm currently attempting to replace the need to use the Excel Interop libraries but moving to [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/). I am hitting a bit of a snag at the moment with the following code:

```
XSSFSheet SheetName = excelWorkbook.GetSheet(sheet);
System.Collections.IEnumerator rows = SheetName.GetRowEnumerator();
while (rows.MoveNext())
{
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)rows.Current;
    foreach (XSSFCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cellContent = cell.StringCellValue;
    } 
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'NPOI.SS.UserModel.ISheet' to 'NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFSheet'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Where am I going wrong? I am certain I haven't any references to HSSF.

Note: I am certain I've made more mistakes than just this, so do point them out to me if you notice anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetSheet method returns a type ISheet, not XSSFSheet.

So, you need to change

```
XSSFSheet SheetName = excelWorkbook.GetSheet(sheet);
```

to

```
XSSFSheet SheetName = (XSSFSheet)excelWorkbook.GetSheet(sheet);
```

explicitly casting the ISheet to XSSFSheet